# Where do I live?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Find the answer:

[image: Location Description Notation Rotation]

Add 3 to my first and put it last,
Add 1 to my new last and keep it second last,
Add 1 to my new second last and put it first,
Add 1 to my old last and put it in the middle,
Minus 1 to my old last, make it small, and put it second.

LOOK AGAIN.

If you don’t understand, you’ll have to translate it. BIT BY BIT.

Comment: hmmm.  I think i followed the instructions but I didn't get the answer.  No typo?

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: i guess the wrong thing if there is no typo!

Comment: I just want to know, what approach did you take?

Comment: hmm may maybe I got something wrong, or missed the final step, as rot-13 "Q a sbhe e fvk" has not yielded information

Comment: I don't think you've done it right, but if you have a partial answer or a guess post it anyway

Comment: I see you changed it completely since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my new re-Edited answer based on changes and further work
My answer is

> Slovenia

Because

> First I looked at the location of the graphic you show, https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2ctA.jpg.   Taking M2ctA, I applied your steps

Add 3 to my first and put it last,

> This gave me M2ctP

Add 1  to my new last and keep it second last,

> This gives M2cQP

Add 1 to my new second last and put it first,

> This gave R2cQP

Add 1 to my old last and put it in the middle,

> This gave R2BQP

Minus 1 to my old last, make it small, and put it second.

> This gives RzBQP

Then I

> looked at https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzBQP.jpg and found an image of a bunch of hex numbers.   Bit by bit, the first 7 hex numbers were the ascii representation of Rossija, which refers to Russia.  Using UTF-8 to decode...

The rest is

> Rossija – svjašcenfaja naša deržava, 
>  Rossija – ljubimaja naša strana. 
>  Mogučaja volja, velikaja slava – 
>  Tvojo dostojanje na vse vremena!

Which

> google translator translates to
>  Russia - our country, 
>  Russia - is kissing our side.
>  
>  Possibly will, great glory - 
>  Your worthiness at all times!

From

> Slovenian.  Thus Slovenia

Comment: I have reset the puzzle, try it now

Comment: What about the other ones?

Comment: i added them now

Comment: Well done! This ia actually the Russian national anthem by the way